# How to create Select query function in the Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want create select function in postgres and get all data from table. I many example see and try but not perfact execute function. What perfact syntax for select query function create in postgres?

My function code.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dataget()
  RETURNS SETOF tbuserlogin AS
$BODY$BEGIN

RETURN QUERY  SELECT * FROM  tbuserlogin;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION dataget()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

This function execute and show the datatable record  but this display record not proper column wise but only one function column display.
Like this

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Is this homework? That function is malformed in such a contrived way that it seems like it must've been done on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function Execute like this And get my Answer

```
select * from functionname();
```